# How to use same code for Mobile and Web in IBM MFP 8.0

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli, mobilefirst-studio

I am a fresher in IBM Mobile first. I need to know How to use one code for mobile and web application.

I have created an IBM MFP Cordova project. My client asking to use the sample Cordova project to the browser(web). I have tried to add the platform for the browser using

```
cordova platform add browser
```

But IBM MFP 8.0 plugin not working for the browser.

Please given solution.

Thanks,
Karthik S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, the MobileFirst plugin for Cordova does not yet support the browser platform. You can use the MobileFirst Web SDK for web apps.

Comment: I have created a web project using NodeJS. How to use the Cordova JS, HTML files to Browser(Web).

Comment: You can copy the web resources into your node sources. See how to deploy using this tutorial https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/development/web/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. There is any other option without copy the sources of Cordova project files? For Reusability.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Srik

Answer (score 1):

The MFP SDK is compatible with cordova browser platform since late 2017:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/09/07/cordova-browser-compatibility-with-MFP/

Depending on whether you want to build a full cross-platform app (browser+app) from the same codebase, you may have to add some cordova hooks to replace some calls to certain functions, as for example the Analytics libraries or the JSONStore SDK are not available on the browser (or their names) differ.

We tried on a Ionic v1 application and the same code of the app works in browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, Edge, but not IE).